# Java/Maven: integrating org.freedesktop.NetworkManager

Tags: java, maven, dbus, networkmanager

Is there a published reliable way to pull the `org.freedesktop.NetworkManager` package into a Maven build?  Searching on https://mvnrepository.com I find [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.jumadeveloper/networkmanager/0.0.2) but I think it's not `org.freedesktop.NetworkManager` and in any case the artifact no longer exists on https://jcenter.bintray.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is normally done in this case is to generate the code using the introspection data.  There are a number of [introspection XML files](https://github.com/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/master/introspection) in the repository for NetworkManager depending on what you're attempting to control.

If you are using the original [dbus-java 2.7 bindings](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-java/), you would use the `CreateInterface` class.  If you are using the updated [3.2 bindings from hypfvieh](https://github.com/hypfvieh/dbus-java), you can generate the code using the [`InterfaceCodeGenerator`](https://github.com/hypfvieh/dbus-java/blob/master/dbus-java-utils/src/main/java/org/freedesktop/dbus/utils/generator/InterfaceCodeGenerator.java) class.  I would recommend using the 3.2 bindings, as a number of bugs have been fixed and it is available via Maven Central.

Comment: Are there instructions anywhere on how to use the InterfaceCodeGenerator?  BTW, I am using the 3.2 bindings form hypfvieh.

Comment: I played around with the InterfaceCodeGenerator but I don't see how it helps.  It has generated, for example,  public interface Wireless extends DBusInterface { ... public void RequestScan(Map<String, Variant<?>> options); ... } but that doesn't give me an implementation of RequestScan.  Yes, I know RequestScan is a DBus method exposed by org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Wireless but it still needs some marshalling code on the client side.

Comment: @Michael You need to use the `Connection.getRemoteObject` method in order to get a remote object to call the methods on.  The library uses reflection to figure out what method you are calling and marshals the data according to that.  See my tutorial for more details: https://rm5248.com/d-bus-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks @rm5248 -- that got me a big step forward but now the code `ssidPoint.RequestScan(new HashMap<String, Variant<?>>())` throws a DBusExecutionException: `Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.16232" (uid=573 pid=4034148 comm="/usr/lib64/jvm/icedtea-bin-8/bin/java -classpath /") interface="org.freedesktop.networkmanager.device.Wireless" member="RequestScan" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" (uid=0 pid=424 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon ")` for which Dr Google fails.

Comment: Fixed the above ^ so I'll leave it for anyone else hunting.  The auto-generated interfaces have the wrong casing on the package names so:  `package org.freedesktop.networkmanager.device;
...

@DBusInterfaceName("org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Wireless")
public interface Wireless extends DBusInterface ...` ... I had to add the annotation myself.

Comment: @Michael in that case, you should probably file a bug report with dbus-java so that it gets fixed for the next person.

Comment: @MichaelrestoreMonicaCellio would it be possible to see your implementation of the framework? I struggle to understand in the 3.2 library how to send the DBus requests...

Comment: @Yvus -- https://pastebin.com/V1B6qS3E -- you will have to supply your own Logger, as that contains proprietary information.

Comment: @MichaelrestoreMonicaCellio Huge thank you. It is not working straight forward. I will try to fix my environment or the code. Let me know if you wish to receive the corrected version if there is one.